# Autenticación Soap con certificado digital en PHP

Tags: php, soap

estoy lidiando con un gran inconveniente el cual es : Autenticarme a un servicio SOAP el cual me pide un certificado para realizarlo. He intentado de muchas maneras y no he tenido éxito, he leído varios ejemplos y documentación pero ninguna me lleva a algo concreto. Tengo la guía de quien provee el servicio y resulta ser que la documentación es para usarlo en un SoapUI ¿Cómo las ves? Le he dado miles de vueltas sin llegar a nada. Si alguien tendria conocimiento o alguun consejo de como yo podría autenticarme se lo agradecería muchisimo.

```
 $url = "https://efactura.dgi.gub.uy:6470/ePrueba/ws_personaGetActEmpresarialPrueba?wsdl";
 $my_cert_file = 'certificate.cer';
// $client = new SoapClient($url);

//   para depurar

 $client = new SoapClient($url, 
 array(
     "local_cert",$my_cert_file,
    "trace" => 1,
    "soap_version" => SOAP_1_2

    )
);


 $fcs = $client->__getFunctions();
 $types = $client->__getTypes();

 echo "cliente<br>";
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($client);
 echo '</pre>';
 

 echo "getfunctions<br>";
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($fcs);
 echo '</pre>';

 echo "getTypes<br>";
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($types);
 echo '</pre>';

 $res  =  $client -> Execute( array ( 'Rut'  =>  '217061580012' ));

 echo "Res<br>";
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($res);
 echo '</pre>';
 die();
```

respuesta

```
 cliente
SoapClient Object
(
    [trace] => 1
    [_stream_context] => Resource id #2
    [_soap_version] => 2
    [sdl] => Resource id #5
)
getfunctions
Array
(
    [0] => WS_PersonaGetActEmpresarial.ExecuteResponse Execute(WS_PersonaGetActEmpresarial.Execute $parameters)
)
getTypes
Array
(
    [0] => struct WS_PersonaGetActEmpresarial.Execute {
 string Rut;
}
    [1] => struct WS_PersonaGetActEmpresarial.ExecuteResponse {
 string Data;
}
)

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [ env:Receiver] Internal Error (from server) in C:\xampp\htdocs\express\soap.php:51 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\express\soap.php(51): SoapClient->__call('Execute', Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\express\soap.php on line 51
```

Esta es la $%&*JTYJTY documentacion https://www.efactura.dgi.gub.uy/files/web-services-consulta-de-rut?es

Comment: Te recomiendo usar el tradicional `cUrl` y envialo de tipo `GET` o `POST` como si fuera un `API REST` pero en lugar de `JSON` envias `XML`, la cual tiene para agregar headers, en donde podras agregar tus token, o la forma de autentiticacion,

Comment: investigare al respecto. Tu dices pasarle parametros en el headers digamos.

Comment: claro, las autenticaciones, firmas, certificados(`HASH`) van en el headers,

Answer (score 0):

Un Ejemplo de como usar `CURL` con `XML`, claro que tienes que cambiar los datos y el `XML`

```
        $file_xml = file_get_contents($data['ruta_file_xml']);
        $soapUrl = $data['ruta_ws'];
        $soapUser = $data['usuario_sol'];
        $soapPassword = $data['pass_sol'];
        $xml_post_string = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.ce.ebiz.com/">
               <soapenv:Header/>
               <soapenv:Body>
                  <ws:invoke>
                     <command><![CDATA['.$file_xml.']]></command>
                  </ws:invoke>
               </soapenv:Body>
            </soapenv:Envelope>';

        $headers = array(
            "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
            "Accept: text/xml",
            "Cache-Control: no-cache",
            "Pragma: no-cache",
            "SOAPAction: ".str_replace("?wsdl", "", $soapUrl),
            "Content-length: " . strlen($xml_post_string),
        );

        $url = $soapUrl;

        $ch = curl_init();
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $soapUser.":".$soapPassword);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 90);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($ch);
        
        if ($httpcode == 200) {
            $doc = new DOMDocument();
            $doc->loadXML($response);
        }
```

Comment: gracias manrrique meneses, una consulta, en caso de que yo no halla generado un usuario ni contraseña?

Comment: Yo cuando solicite el certificado digital, por mi inexperiencia en el tema hice lo siguiente: 1 ) Genere una key en openssl la cual me genero dos archivos = archivo.csr y archivo.key, yo sin saber, use la key del archivo.csr y la copie y pegue en la solicitud del certificado, e investigando me di cuenta que tenia que haber colocado la key del archivo.key. Sim embargo me dieron un certificado digital. Que me vine solo una clave encriptada. No vino como un archivo, yo mismo quise convertirlo a un archivo.cer